# More Float Right Questions

Tags: html, css

Here's the link: http://www.whiterootmedia.com/homepage_layout_test/

Here's the code:

```
<div class="site" style="background:yellow;min-width: 577px; "> 

<div class="banner" style="background:blue; height:100px; width:417px; float:left;">Banner   Banner   Banner   Banner   Banner   </div>
<div class="ads" style="background:green; height:800px; width:160px; float:right;">Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  </div>
<div class="tree" style="background:orange; white-space:nowrap; height:400px; width:auto; min-width:417px; clear:left;">Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   </div>

</div>
```

I would like the Orange div content not to go behind or on top of the green div when you shrink the window and  I would like the orange div text to push the green div off the screen.

Dusty

Answer (score 0):

Use the css property "z-index".

For example:

```
.onTop {
    z-index: 1;
}
.onBottom {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The higher the number, the more "on-top" the element is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance trying to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/d7seY/

Note: I changed some measurements so it was a bit more comfortable to lay out in jsfiddle.

Comment: nope. hello world text should push the purple text off the screen

Comment: Should the text go under it or should the purple area just be pushed off screen?... Sounds pretty close to impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

- Remove "white-space:nowrap;" (but I assume you have some reason for that)
- Add an overflow:hidden to the orange div.  This will simply chop off the overflowing text -- it won't go either behind or on top of the green div.

But if you keep the "white-space:nowrap", and that line of "Tree" text doesn't fit, it has to go somewhere....  your options are behind, on top of, or getting chopped off with overflow:hidden.

Let me know if I'm missing what you are after.